# Expand input field width smoothly on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display an input field `.search` when clicking on `.icon` class. I have managed to do that with following code. However instead of show/hide, I want to display the input field by smoothly expanding its width.

How that can be done?

**JSFiddle Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9nPW9/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
    <input class="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
     <div class="icon"></div>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box{
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
}

.search {    
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
      -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    float: left;
}


.icon{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red; 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.icon').click(function() {
    $('.search').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not change your code to toggle a class, thus keeping a clear separation between functionality (JS) and style (CSS)

Below is some sample code, you will likely want to edit for your precise needs.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nPW9/4/)

JS

```
$('.icon').click(function() {
    $('.search').toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

CSS

```
 .box {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
}
.search {
    width: 200px;
    max-width:0;
    padding: 5px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    opacity:0;
}
.search.expanded {
    max-width:200px;
    opacity:1;
}
.icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.slideToggle()` or `fadeToggle()`

```
$('.icon').click(function() {
    $('.search').slideToggle(500);
});
```