# How to expand search-bar on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a search icon that expands on click. The icon is an svg. I created a separate class for expansion and on click, the expanded class is added to the icon. Javascript is used for this operation. The problem is when I wrap in svg button or an anchor tag and click on the icon the desired action does not take place. Further, when I center my navbar using left:50% and transform it to -50%, it messes up with the style of the expanded class. How to solve both of these? I am attaching part of the code below.

```js
const searchContainer = document.querySelector('.search-bar');
const searchInput = document.querySelector('.search-button');
const closeButton2 = document.getElementById("search-close");
const clearButton = document.getElementById("clear-button");
const htmlElement = document.body;


searchInput.addEventListener('click', function() {
  searchContainer.classList.add('expanded');
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!searchContainer.contains(event.target)) {
    searchContainer.classList.remove('expanded');

  }
});
```

```css
.expanded {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0rem;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: 'red';
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main-navbar {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.search-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: -2px;
}

.search-button svg {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.search-button svg {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.expanded .search-button {
  display: none;
}

.search-bar.expand {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.search-bar.expanded form {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

.expanded .search {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.search {
  display: none;
}

.search-bar.expanded .search {
  display: block;
}

.search-bar.expanded .suggestion-box {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 800px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px #c8c8c8;
}

.search-bar.expanded {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.suggestion-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-navbar">

  <div class="search-bar">
    <form>
      <input class="search " placeholder="Search">
      <a class="search-button" href="">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
                           <rect width="256" height="256" fill="none"/>
                           <circle cx="116" cy="116" r="84" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="14"/>
                           <line x1="175.4" y1="175.4" x2="224" y2="224" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="14"/>
                        </svg>
      </a>
    </form>
    <div class="suggestion-box">
      <p> Popular Search</p>
      <p>Shoes</p>
      <p>shirts</p>
      <p>Jackets</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expand input field width smoothly on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138735/expand-input-field-width-smoothly-on-click)

Comment: hey @adampweb, no, not exactly because my problem is related to the selection of the div and how the position of my navbar is disturbing the style of and position of my expanded class

Comment: Pass   event.preventDefault(); in this function searchInput.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

here is correct code

```
.expanded {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0rem;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: 'red';
    z-index: 1000;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

.main-navbar {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 17px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.search-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: -2px;
}

.search-button svg {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.search-button svg {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.search:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.expanded .search-button {
    display: none;
}

.search-bar.expand {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.search-bar.expanded form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
}

.expanded .search {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.search {
    display: none;
}

.search-bar.expanded .search {
    display: block;
}

.search-bar.expanded .suggestion-box {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 800px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 1px #c8c8c8;
}

.search-bar.expanded {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.suggestion-box {
    display: none;
}
.close{
    display: none;
}
.list{
    list-style-type:none;
}

<div class="main-navbar">
<div class="search-bar" id="searchBox">
    <form>
        <div onclick="searchData()">
        <input id="searchText" class="search " placeholder="Search">
        <a class="search-button">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
                <rect width="256" height="256" fill="none" />
                <circle cx="116" cy="116" r="84" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="14" />
                <line x1="175.4" y1="175.4" x2="224" y2="224" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round"
                    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="14" />
            </svg>
        </a>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="suggestionBox" class="suggestion-box" >
        <ul id="list" class="list">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
(function() {
    var data=["Popular Search","Shoes","shirts","Jackets"];
    var ul = document.getElementById("list");
    data.forEach(element => {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(element));
        li.setAttribute("id", element);
        li.addEventListener("click",closeSesrch); 
        ul.appendChild(li);
    });
})();


function searchData() {
    const searchContainer = document.getElementById('searchBox');
    searchContainer.classList.add('expanded');
    const suggestionbox = document.getElementById('suggestionBox');
    suggestionbox.classList.add('suggestion-box');
    suggestionbox.classList.remove('close');
}
function closeSesrch(){
    document.getElementById('searchText').value=this.id;
    const suggestionbox = document.getElementById('suggestionBox');
    suggestionbox.classList.remove('suggestion-box');
    suggestionbox.classList.add('close');
}
```